# Stored Procedure in sql server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I use the following function for insert the value in database through the stored procedure.but i have the exception in `sqlConnection.Open()`;How to solve this?

```
  try
        {
            string dbConnectionString = "something";
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_Test", sqlConnection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id ", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
            sqlConnection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SQL Error" + ex.Message.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: You haven't explained what the exception is.

Comment: What exception are you getting? Are you sure the actual connection string is correct (the correct server, the correct login credentials)?

Comment: As a programming side note: use the `using` statement to scope your expensive resources.

Comment: I put this as comment because I can't think that this is related to your problem. The syntax for AddWithValue is `AddWithValue(string paramName, object paramValue)`. What are you doing is: Add a parameter named @ID with value SqlDbType.Int, then the return value is a SqlParameter and you add the correct value, but... on the string FullName this wreak havoc.....

Comment: I get this Exception:A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error you are getting doesn't really have anything to do with stored procedures, but I can answer the question of "how to solve this?" in the context of the exception you are getting.

First, I hope you are not using "something" as the actual connection string to your sql server.  You should be using a real connection string.  Here are some various examples you can use to connect to SQLServer - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Using the first example from the above url

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You'll want to change "myServerAddress" to the ip address or host name of the server.  This could be "localhost" or it could be another computer you have on the network.  Change "myDataBase" to the name of the database you created, and make sure the name matches exactly as the database might be configured with case sensitivity.  And finally change "myUsername" and "myPassword" to the user and password of the account you use to access the server under Sql Server Management Studio.

Now, assuming you have actually done the above, here are some steps you can take to debug connection issues.

1. Ping the computer - from and command prompt type "ping servername" where servername is the name or ip address of the server that runs SQL Server.  If you don't get a response from the server then you need to debug your local network.
2. If the server is running locally try using "." for the "myServerAddress" value. If it's sqlserver express edition, use the express format - ".\SQLExpress" or "myServerAddress\SQLExpress"
3. If SQL Server is running on another computer try each of the three links under the section "More Information" from this kb article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277  That will ensure remote connections are supported.

But the real issue is that you cannot connect to the database.  I recommend searching for solutions to that problem first.  Or perhaps supply more information about your setup here on SO in a different question.

Hope that helps,
-Marcus